# jquery ui datepicker like input widget

Tags: javascript, jquery

i' like to make some jquery widget, which will have behavior like jquery ui datepicker:
it should appears when focus on input tag and this widget and should be hidden when
user mouse focus not in this widget and input tag,
can you help me to say the right way to implement this behavior

thanks

Comment: just rip it off, and modify it

Answer (score 1):

look at re: in this page:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/invoke-function-on-datepicker-cell-hover

Answer (score 1):

i think you should use one of datepickers like this one http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ it is easy to use and probably implementing will take shorter time than developing it